# Vista / Windows Server 2003 Mapped Drive Logon Failure

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-vista, netlogon

I have a Windows Vista (Ultimate) machine which connects to a Windows Server 2003 machine for just one thing: a mapped network drive.

There is a user account on the Server machine which **exactly** matches the user name & password on the Vista machine.

The problem is... when I try to connect (map) the network drive, a message comes up saying the user name or password was incorrect! Since it then gives you the opportunity to re-enter the user name and password, I re-enter the password (exactly the same, again) and it works and the drive gets mapped.

BUT... the plot thickens! After a reboot (or, I suppose, a log-off and log-on), the network drive doesn't work anymore - double clicking it gives a short delay, and then a message saying the drive can't be reconnected because the account has been locked out. Sure enough, checking on the server shows the account locked out. A glance at the event log shows repeated "invalid password" events before the account is eventually locked out.

The specific events that are recorded are:

- A logon attempt by `MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0`, which fails with code `0xC0000234`
- A "logon failure" event which says "unknown user name or bad password."

  - The user name specified in the event is the user name I'm using
  - The "logon type" is "3"
  - The logon process is "NtLmSsp"
  - The authentication package is NTLM

Both machines are using the same LAN manager authentication method (specifically, "Send LM & NTLM, use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated") - set via security policy.

The Vista machine is not part of the domain, but the user name and password match.

The Vista machine *used* to work just fine, back when it was an XP machine. But then, it got upgraded to Vista (not a clean re-install, an actual upgrade) and this is what happens now.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why it seems to be sending the wrong password, when I have checked & double-checked to make sure the password is *exactly* the same. I've googled & googled and found nothing useful. I'm stumped!

Does anyone have any ideas as to what *might* be happening here - or ideas for further troubleshooting steps I can take?

**UPDATE:** I've tried mapping the drive via the command line and the NET USE command - but it throws up its hands as well, with a "system error 86" which says "the specified network password is not correct." Your guess is as good as mine as to what's really going on here. I wish I could sniff the actual traffic going back & forth between the computers and see what password (if any!!) is being sent...

Answer (score 2):

i have had similar problems. it seems to be related to logging in to a different server with a different password. for instance, i had a user password for one share and a different one for another - both with the same login id. after i attached both of the shares, it would forever mess up logging into one of them. even *after* i no longer used one of them, the remaining one always prompted me to login. the solution that seemed to fix it for me was:

1. removed all network mapped drives
2. i remapped everything on the command line: net use z: \myserver\theshare /persistent:yes

after doing that, the drive map worked fine. windows seems to be saving authentication for old shares and gets confused.

-don

Comment: Thanks; I will give that a try, but still I wish I knew what was going on "under the hood" - since it's clear that whatever the Vista machine is sending is not what the Win2k3 machine is expecting...

Comment: Tried that - sadly, no luck. I wish I could "see" what credentials are actually being sent!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different username and password ?

Can you also please post the security log from the server / workstation. That would help in figuring out the issue.

Also check out this post on these type of errors:

http://  x-security.blogspot.com/2009/04/trobleshoot-user-account-lockout.  html

Comment: The entry from the security event log is part of the question; I have tried changing the user's password and trying that with no luck; I haven't tried with a different user name - I assume that a different user will work fine, since this problem is affecting just one user!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the user is running Windows 2008 which was not attached to the domain (also happens on Vista I believe) and I was trying to map to a NAS (not a real server).

The fix was,
Go to Admin Tools >> Local Security Policy >> Local Policies >> Security Options >> Network security: LAN Manager authentication level --> change this value to Send LM & NTLM responses

I guess this is a less secure setting but it resolved the issue.

BTW... Also important to check the time on the workstation and server are within 5 minutes of each other.

-TamW

Answer (score 0):

This last suggestion with the LM & NTLM responses setting worked for me. I was trying to access shares on a W2K pro from a Windows 7 pro. Same user names and passwords, no domain, just a workgroup. Without this setting, I was able to access remote shares just fine, then it just quit working and started asking for credentials, which no matter if they were correct, would refuse access. I think the setting must have been changed from a windows update.